# Downloading and showing images in the appropriate cell

Tags: ios, image, uitableview, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I download an image per each cell I need to show in an `UITableView` by calling an async network task. This is in the `UIViewController` class of the table:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard results.count > 0 else {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CustomCell.cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    let model = results[indexPath.row]
    myCell.model = model
    return myCell
}
```

And this is `CustomCell`:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

// Several IBOutlets

static let cellIdentifier = "myCell"
let imageProvider = ImageProvider()

var model: MyModel? {
willSet {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    configureImage(showImage: false, showActivity: true)
}
didSet {
    guard let modelUrlStr = model?.imageUrlStr, let imageUrl = URL(string: modelUrlStr) else {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        configureImage(showImage: false, showActivity: false)
        return
    }

    imageProvider.getImage(imageUrl: imageUrl, completion: {[weak self] (image, error) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard error == nil else {
                self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self?.configureImage(showImage: false,  showActivity: false)
                return
            }

            self?.imageView.image = image
            self?.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            self?.configureImage(showCoverImage: true, showActivity: false)
        }
    })
}
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()
configureImage(showCoverImage: false, showActivity: false)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
super.prepareForReuse()
model = nil
}

private func configureImage(showImage: Bool, showActivity: Bool) {
// Update image view
} 
}
```

And `ImageProvider`:

```
class ImageProvider {
var imageTask: URLSessionDownloadTask?

func getImage(imageUrl: URL, completion: @escaping DownloadResult) {
imageTask?.cancel()

imageTask = NetworkManager.sharedInstance.getImageInBackground(imageUrl: imageUrl, completion: { (image, error) -> Void in
    if let error = error {
        completion(nil, error)
    } else if let image = image {
        completion(image, nil)
    } else {
        completion(nil, nil)
    }
})
}
}
```

Since cells can be dynamically dequeued and reused and the download is async and then an image could be reused on each cell while scrolling, am I this way ensuring that each cell is always showing its corresponding image?

**EDIT: Different approach**

Is it appropriate to keep a reference to the model in the cell? Thinking about a correct `MVC` architecture. Who should be the responsible for downloading the images? The cell (passing to it only the URL instead of the complete model object), or the table view's view controller (updating the image in the cell in its `tableView:cellForRowAt:` method)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a method to your `ImageProvider` that would allow you to cancel the underlying `URLSessionDownloadTask`. Call this method when the cell is about to be reused. For that, override `prepareForReuse()` in your cell subclass.
2. There is a possibility that the task will already finish by the time reuse happens, but the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block is still enqueued and will be fired after cell reuse has happened. To mitigate this, you need to check the URL that the of the finished task against the URL that is stored in your model.

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking... actually is it correct to have the model in the cell? That breaks `MVC` pattern, right? I have seen some examples doing like that, passing the model to the cell and handling the network download there, but would it be more appropriate to move such logic to the table view's view controller?

Comment: @AppsDev I would advise doing the thing that feels less awkward to you. If strict adherence to architectural pattern makes you add complexity for an unclear benefit, I'd say avoid it. Having stuff done like in your example may be perfectly alright in this case. It depends on how your system is structured. Follow your gut feelings :)